# Zooming in from the side on the hover

Tags: javascript, html, css

Does anyone know if there is a pure javascript library to do a product zoom from the side?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nJeLv.png)

I can't find a solution in pure javascript

Comment: There are so many different questions that solved this problem with pure javascript. It's just a google search away...

Comment: I have to concur with GucciB. And searching codepen with *zoom image* I found [this](https://codepen.io/dragoweb/pen/ARXvXR) easy example within seconds. No need for a JS library, just vanilla CSS using `transform: scale(..)`, possibly combined with `translateX(..)`. And to remind you: on SO a [reprex] is your friend...